# Set value of var in foreach - Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hope/suspect this is easy, so I will ask here and make a fool out of my self if it is.

I have a foreach loop in my view, mind you this is a Razor view.  I dont know if the ASP.NET View engine does the same... but it might.  I want to flip a bool on each loop, but it does not see to let me.  The view engine chokes to death.  Why?  How can I fix it?  I did a for loop and I did mod 2 for now, but I really need to understand this.

This is what I tried:

```
@{
    var IsOdd = false;
}
@foreach(var foo in bar)
{
    @{ IsOdd = !IsOdd; }
    <div class="@(IsOdd ? "odd" : "even")">@foo</div>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{
    var IsOdd = false;
}
@foreach(var foo in bar)
{
    IsOdd = !IsOdd;
    <div class="@(IsOdd ? "odd" : "even")">@foo</div>
}
```

(Worked for me with MVC 3 RC.)

Comment: Well I almost tried that, but then I thought, no that would never work.  Strange this new razor is.

Comment: I guess that makes sense the more I look at it.

Comment: Seems to be a lot of trial and error.  Interestingly, the SO syntax highlighter really chokes on Razor syntax.